# CakePHP add default routing extension

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I've got a JSON REST api working for my application at a URL like: `website.com/model/data.json` using the [CakePHP REST Simple Setup](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html).

But I'd like it to also work the same even if I don't use the .json extension (in other words the response from `website.com/model/data.json` should be the same as `website.com/model/data`).

Is there any way to set an implied/default extension for a given controller function such that this would work?

FWIW: I'm using CakePHP 2.3.

Comment: You mean you want to output JSON even though the url doesn't have the `.json` extension? Why? That would be "non-standard" REST.  After all, humans should never see JSON or have to type in .json urls, so why do this?

Comment: That's what I'm interested in doing.  I was looking to make my API URLs prettier and more consistent.  What about a way to define a route (without a .json extension) to a .json URL instead?

Comment: Prettier? Removing the extension makes them harder to use because of the ambiguity.  Take a look at the APIs for all the big players; they all use extensions.

Comment: Regardless any potential ambiguity or personal design decisions; I'm still interested in getting an answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set up a route in CakePHP, add the following to your routes.php file:

```
Router::connect(
    '/model/data',
    array('controller' => 'model', 'action' => 'data', 'ext' => 'json')
);
```

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html for more details on routing.

Comment: Great.  I was trying 'data.json' instead of using the 'ext' argument.  Thanks.